# How to use the divide function in the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to show the percentage for the Overshipment column.

My sample query

```
select (SPGI09_EARLY_OVER_T – (SPGI09_OVER_WK_EARLY_ADJUST_T) / (SPGI09_EARLY_OVER_T + SPGR99_LATE_CM_T  + SPGR99_ON_TIME_Q))
from 
CSPGI09_OVERSHIPMENT
```

Table Name - CSPGI09_OVERSHIPMENT

My formula:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
SPGI09_EARLY_OVER_T – (SPGI09_OVER_WK_EARLY_ADJUST_T)
-------------------------------------------------------
SPGI09_EARLY_OVER_T + SPGR99_LATE_CM_T  + SPGR99_ON_TIME_Q
```

and I want to show the result with %,  for example, 66.57%

I'm using SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Have you tried running this? If so did it work (you can manually calculate the values yourself) - if not then give some more details

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming all of these columns are `int`, then the first thing to sort out is converting one or more of them to a better data type - `int` division performs truncation, so anything less than 100% would give you a result of 0:

```
select (100.0 * (SPGI09_EARLY_OVER_T – SPGI09_OVER_WK_EARLY_ADJUST_T)) / (SPGI09_EARLY_OVER_T + SPGR99_LATE_CM_T  + SPGR99_ON_TIME_Q)
from 
CSPGI09_OVERSHIPMENT
```

Here, I've mutiplied one of the numbers by `100.0` which will force the result of the calculation to be done with `float`s rather than `int`s. By choosing `100`, I'm also getting it ready to be treated as a `%`.

I was also a little confused by your bracketing - I think I've got it correct - but you had brackets around single values, and then in other places you had a mix of operators (`-` and `/`) at the same level, and so were relying on the precedence rules to define which operator applied first.

Comment: If it returns null, then one or more of your input columns contains a null. You can wrap them in `COALESCE(Column,0)` or `COALESCE(Column,1)`, or whatever else you want to do when the column is null.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How can i append the % with the values ?

Comment: Convert to a string, using `CONVERT(varchar(20),<result>)` and then append the `%`, using `+ '%'`

Comment: How can i get the 2 digit values from the decimal(.).For Example 23.34%

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
select Cast((SPGI09_EARLY_OVER_T – (SPGI09_OVER_WK_EARLY_ADJUST_T) / (SPGI09_EARLY_OVER_T + SPGR99_LATE_CM_T  + SPGR99_ON_TIME_Q)) as varchar(20) + '%' as percentageAmount
from CSPGI09_OVERSHIPMENT
```

I presume the value is a representation in percentage - if not convert it to a valid percentage total, then add the % sign and convert the column to varchar.